# Unique constraint on 2 fields (where xpath of fields refer to different attributes in different nodes)

Tags: xml, xsd

I have

```
<Account name="abc">
    <Parameters type="standard"/>
</Account>

<Account name="abc">
    <Parameters type="standard"/>
</Account>
```

and I'm having no success doing this

```
   <xs:unique name="unique-Accounts">
            <xs:selector xpath="ns:Account"/>
            <xs:field xpath="Parameters/@type"/>
   </xs:unique>
```

eventually I would like to do something like:

```
   <xs:unique name="unique-Accounts">
            <xs:selector xpath="ns:Account"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
            <xs:field xpath="Parameters/@type"/>
   </xs:unique>
```

but my stumbling block is the `Parameters/@type` xpath

Why doesn't this work?

If I try to make it unique on just `@name` that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're just **missing the namespace prefix inside `xs:field`**. So this works:

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com"
    xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Account" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Parameters">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="unique-Accounts">
            <xs:selector xpath="ns:Account"/>
            <xs:field xpath="ns:Parameters/@type"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com xsd.xsd">
    <Account name="abc">
        <Parameters type="standard"/>
    </Account>

    <Account name="abc">
        <Parameters type="standard"/>
    </Account>
</root>
```

Comment: I assume this is the correct answer because that's what I thought too (I  tried with and without the ns before posting).. I still can't get it to work though in my actual XSD / XML files.I use a lot of `xs:unique` in my XSD but I only have problem with this `ns:Account` one but, it's the only one I've tried to constrain based upon information in a child node

Comment: I've updated my answer to add a complete example that works, hope it can help you with your real XSD